# Loading Plaid Link Web SDK using webpack

Tags: webpack, cdn, plaid

I am working on creating a vanilla js web app using webpack. I've used HtmlWebpackPlugin with html-loader in my webpack configuration.

The problem I'm facing is that [Plaid Link](https://plaid.com/docs/link/web/) Web SDK should be used through `<script>` tags. Using webpack however, I am getting a cors error. For loading cdn scripts, I've followed [this](https://sebastianrothbucher.github.io/web/html/css/javascript/webpack/cdn/2018/09/22/webpack-javascript-css-cdn.html#:%7E:text=Webpack%20is%20a%20great%20tool,Tree%20Shaking%2C%20etc.).) article which uses externals.

I've tried searching for similar issues to no avail.

Edit: The configuration is the same as outlined in this boilerplate

Edit Edit: The webpack config is:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const TerserJSPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash:8].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js"
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader" // transpiling our JavaScript files using Babel and webpack
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: "html-loader",
          options: {
            minimize: true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin()],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          chunks: "all"
        }
      },
      chunks: "all"
    },
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: "runtime"
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    // CleanWebpackPlugin will do some clean up/remove folder before build
    // In this case, this plugin will remove 'dist' and 'build' folder before re-build again
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // This plugin will extract all css to one file
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[chunkhash:8].bundle.css",
      chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.css",
    }),
    // The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that includes all your webpack bundles in the body using script tags
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      favicon: "src/assets/skyflow-favicon.png"
    }),
    // ComppresionPlugin will Prepare compressed versions of assets to serve them with Content-Encoding.
    // In this case we use gzip
    // But, you can also use the newest algorithm like brotli, and it's supperior than gzip
    new CompressionPlugin({
      algorithm: "gzip"
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    }
  },
  externals: {
    "Plaid": "Plaid"
  }
};
```

Comment: can you provide the full text of the CORS error in your question?

Comment: @Alex The full text is: `Access to script at 'https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js' from origin 'http://192.168.0.162:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you provide, it sounds like the issue may be that you are locally running your server on http rather than https. There are several ways to set up https for testing, the easiest is probably via mkcert.

If that doesn't resolve the issue, I'd suggest submitting a ticket to Plaid support via the Plaid Dashboard.